# How does TalkBack works with a braille display?

Tags: accessibility, talk-back

I am new to Android development. I have a doubt with regard to the Android TalkBack feature and how it is used with a braille display. In my project, I'm trying to use this TalkBack feature to print/display the text on the screen to a braille reading device (for example: Orbit Reader 20).

I don't know how the Android TalkBack feature scans for nearby braille displays/reading devices. I know it sends some packets to and from the braille display/reading device, but I don't know what exactly they are.

Any help would be appreciated, including documentation/resources! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while this community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, you might want to try our sister site [so]. Also, we discourage link-only Q&A but instead encourage self-contained answers. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: As you are new, on the sister site StackOverflow it is up to the post author to do research on the topic. I would look at any hardware braille reader manufacturer's website looking for either a developer SDK, a press release announcements, or a list of supported applications (perhaps some are open-source) to lead you to an answer or provide direction for further research. Good luck.